# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 on LG gram style2023

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, ssd, samsung, lg

I'm worried about driver issues.
I have a samsung t7 sheid SSD ,can I use it to boot ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has two standard kernel choices; the ISO used at download will dictate which stack exists on that ISO used to install (5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13, & 5.15 are available for Desktop ISOs, and 5.4 only for Sever - you didn't specify which), but once upgraded you'll be using 5.4 or 5.15 (*I'm ignoring OEM kernel stacks here*). The kernel used controls the kernel modules being used (kernel modules ~= *drivers*) so you have some choice before you download. You can try it before install to work out how well it works too (5 kernels exist on ISOs to try)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)